# How can I permute a multiset?

Tags: list-manipulation, packed-arrays, permutation

I have a multiset {1, 3, 3, 1, 2} and would like to randomly permute the classes like so: {2, 1, 1, 2, 3} or {3, 2, 2, 3, 1}, what is the simplest and most efficient way to do this?

In reality the input set would be like `RandomInteger[1000, 1000000]`

*Edit*

The tricky part of this question is that the positions of the same integers must remain the same! Only the representatives are permuted, but the positions of the classes of integers need to remain the same.

Comment: RandomSample does not preserve the structure.

Comment: For the not-so-bright among us, could you explain how the two sets are permutations of each other and how the positions of the integers remain the same? I don't see theconnection. I see you've been referring answerers to your example, but the example is unhelpful

Comment: @r.m. As I understand it the integers should be seen as  labels for various items on fixed locations. Duplicate items are possible (and they have corresponding labels). What Mike wants is to swap the labels but not the items.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
list = RandomInteger[1000,1000000];
rules = Dispatch@Thread[Range[0, 1000] -> RandomSample[Range[0, 1000]]];
newlist = list /. rules;
```

`Thread` creates rules for the integers from 1-1000 to a random permutation of the same integers. `/.`then does the replacement.

Edit: I added `Dispatch` as per Oleksandr R.'s comment. It cuts the time on my machine from 8.3 seconds to 0.2 seconds.

Comment: Another way, much faster still: `(RandomSample@Range[0, 1000])[[list + 1]]`.

Comment: @Oleksandr That method deserves an answer of its own.  Why don't you post it?